# Best way to get file date created from Java on a UNIX system?

Tags: java, macos, file, unix, time

java.io.File doesn't provide a way to get a file's creation date.  You can get file.lastModified, but not anything like dateCreated.

Java 7 adds the excellent java.nio.file package with access to date created, but it's not out yet.

My question: what's the best way to get a file's date created from Java on a UNIX/OSX system?  I suppose it's executing a shell script, but my command line skills are pretty weak.  So if shell scripting's the way to go, if you could provide a full example I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: First I would check you are using a file system which records the creation date as most do not. Which file system are you using?

Comment: If you are using OSX, you can google for solutions like `ls -lcT datetest.txt`  http://blog.sudosu.net/2009/file-created-date-under-os-x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line, the easiest way to get the creation date is with `mdls`. I think you'd want to do `/usr/bin/mdls -name kMDItemFSCreationDate $filename` (where `$filename` is the file you're asking about). You can specify multiple filenames, but that might make it harder to parse the output.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine on OSX!  Seems like my linux server simply doesn't store the date created, so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Dean: That's correct. The POSIX standard does not define a creation time, so most Linux/Unix filesystems do not store them.

Answer (score 2):

Unix doesn't have a "creation date". The only dates stored on files are modification date, which stores the time the file contents where changed; the access date, which stores the last time a file was read; and the "change date", which stores the last time the file's metadata was changed. (The metadata contains things like permission bits, ownership, etc.)

If you review the structure supported by the stat(2) API, you can see the three timespec's.

Comment: I just noticed that Darwin and FreeBSD have a fourth timespec, st_birthtimespec. Okay, so POSIX doesn't support a birthtime...

Comment: RedHat Linux does not have a st_birthtimespec in its stat structure.

Comment: Thanks.  Used stat on a file on my filesystem and sure enough, it returns a modify date but not a create date.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - it isn't stored anywhere

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the file system, and most file systems don't provide such feature as storing a file "birth time". You need to check the filesystem.